# MySQL Workbench gives error on Fedora 20

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, fedora

I see error when I run MySQL Workbench.

```
/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: relocation error: /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libmysqlcppconn.so.7: symbol mysql_server_init, version libmysqlclient_18 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.18 with link time reference
```

Here is related bug that says it is a bug in Fedora.
https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-6270

But for now, I cannot run workbench. Is there a way to manually install correct file from somewhere else? Or is there a way to download MySQL Workbench that actually works?

Comment: Perhaps use different distro or tool other than MySQL workbench?  This is really not a good question for SO, as there is nothing for us to really do here if there is already a known bug.  A this point you are in essence asking for tool-specific recommendations.

Comment: Thanks Mike Brant and sorry if it is not meant tob e for SO. 

I was wondering if there is a command to actually load any previous versions of MysqlWorkbench and whether that will actually works.

If none, I will go and use another tool.

Comment: Obviously MySQL Workbench works best with the MySQL server. Why using MariaDB then? You wouldn't have the problem in the first place if you'd use software that belongs together.

Comment: MySQL Workbench works with MariaDB as per this [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/guiworkbench-for-mariadb-aria/).

I am using MariDB because that is what `yum install mysql` installed for me.

Anyway, I installed squirrel-sql client for now and it seems to be working.

Will figure out what is the difference between mysql community edition vs MariaDB later.

Answer (score 1):

1. install mysql fedora repo from here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/
2. install mysql-community-client package

Comment: Is that Repo URL correct? I get following error..
`
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
`
And `yum install` fails

Comment: could you please open this link in browser?

Comment: I get 404 when I open the link in browser.